# WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment. Node 18 Vesion

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, node-modules, config

Here I am trying to configure Nodejs to MSsql through Sequelize ORM. I could not get many references and previous threads on the error i was getting **To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment. **

My Node JS version: 18.12.1 LTS.

Below I have shared my configuration folder structure in backend.

[image: configuration folder structure]

Here I am sharing my package.json libraries version to be more clear.

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Business-Tool",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Shivaram",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "config": "^3.3.8",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "log4js": "^6.7.0",
    "node-sspi": "^0.2.10",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "sequelize": "^6.25.5",
    "tedious": "^15.1.1"
  }
}
```

**db.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const config = require('config');
const log4js = require('log4js');
const logger = log4js.getLogger();
logger.level = 'debug';

const dbName = config.get("dbName");
const dbUser = config.get("dbUser");
const dbPassword = config.get("dbPassword");

module.exports = new Sequelize(dbName, dbUser, dbPassword,{
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mssql',
    logging: false,
    timezone : '+05:30'
});
```

**default.json**

```
{
    "dbName": "BusinessTool",
    "dbUser": "shiva",
    "dbPassword": "Businesstool2022" 
}
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const log4js = require('log4js')
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const config = require('config');
const nodeSSPI = require('node-sspi');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Logger Configuration
let date = new Date();
let today = date.toDateString();
log4js.configure({
    appenders:{
        fileAppender:{
            type: 'file',
            filename: `./logs/${today}.log`,
            maxLogSize: 5000000,
            compress:true
        }
    },
    categories:{
        default:{
            appenders: ['fileAppender'],
            level : 'info'
        }
    }
});

const logger = log4js.getLogger();
logger.level = 'info';

//CORS
var corsOptions = {
    origin: ['http://localhost:4200'],
    Credentials: true 
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

//Database
const db = require('./config/db');
const  { hostname } = require('os');
const dbName = config.get("dbName")

db.authenticate()
.then(() => {
    logger.info(`Connected to Database: ${dbName}`);
    console.log(`Connected to Database: ${dbName}`)
})

.catch(err =>{
    logger.error(`Failed to connect to Database: ${dbName} - ${err} - ${new Error().stack}`);
    console.log(`Failed to connect to Database: ${dbName}`);
})

//Node-SSPI
app.use((req, res, next) =>{
    const nodeSSPIObj = new nodeSSPI({
        retireveGroups:true
    })
    nodeSSPIObj.authenticate(req, res, (err) => {
        res.finished || next();
    })
});


//Server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log(`Server listening at PORT: ${PORT}`);

})
```

I have installed nodemon package globally and tried to run with command

```
nodemon app.js
```

I was getting the below error :

> WARNING: No configurations found in configuration
> directory:D:\Projects\Business-Tool\Backend\config WARNING: To disable
> this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment.
> D:\Projects\Business-Tool\Backend\node_modules\config\lib\config.js:179
> throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined');

Can someone let me know how to overcome on this or any environment variables need to be added?

Comment: Where is `default.json` located?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski default.json and db.js file are inside config folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem. My mistake was that the `config` folder was inside the `src` folder. For this to work, the `config` folder with configuration files must be in the **root directory**.